# How can I remove vertical scrolling in datatable if I zoom 67%

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

In my html `Jquery data table` I don't want vertical and horizontal scrolling 
so in normal zoom(100%) that table are display properly this is good but if I reduce zoom(67%) at that time vertical scrolling are come so how can I remove this vertical scrolling?

This is my normal image that I want

[image: Normal image]

This image is for 67% zoom

[image: 67% zoom image]

Here is my datatable code:

```
<table  datatable="ng" dt-options="table.dtOpt_SalesEntry" dt-column-defs="table.dtColDefs_SalesEntry" class="row-border hover table-responsive display nowrap">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_sr'| translate}}</th>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_qtyorder'| translate}}</th>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_qtypur'| translate}}</th>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_unit'| translate}}</th>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_uprice'| translate}}</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Feb.</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Labor</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Material</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Nre.</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Stencil</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Design</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Other</th>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_action'| translate}}</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_sr'| translate}}</th>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_qtyorder'| translate}}</th>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_qtypur'| translate}}</th>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_unit'| translate}}</th>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_uprice'| translate}}</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Feb.</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Labor</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Material</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Nre.</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Stencil</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Design</th>
        <th class="thbg">Charge Other</th>
        <th class="thbg">{{'salesorder.sales_action'| translate}}</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="list in table.process_data.sale_entry">
        <td>{{ $index + 1}}</td>
        <td>{{ list.qty_ordered}}</td>
        <td>{{ list.qty_purchased}}</td>
        <td>{{ list.entryunit}}</td>
        <td>{{ list.unit_price}}</td>
        <td>{{list.charge_fab}}</td>
        <td>{{list.charge_labor}}</td>
        <td>{{list.charge_material}}</td>
        <td>{{list.charge_nre}}</td>
        <td>{{list.charge_stencil}}</td>
        <td>{{list.charge_design}}</td>
        <td>{{list.charge_other}}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning tbar" ng-click="table.editEntry($index);table.SalesEntryInput = true" uib-tooltip="{{'crm.TOOLTIPMSG.EDITBUTTON'|translate}}" uib-tooltip-trigger="focus" uib-tooltip-placement="top" ><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger tbar" ng-click="table.demo5('entry', list.id)" uib-tooltip="{{'crm.TOOLTIPMSG.DELETEMSG'|translate}}" uib-tooltip-trigger="focus" uib-tooltip-placement="top" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What have you tried, etc... there is no css to help you with either, and finally, there is nothing like zoom level in css only media queries, which work with canvas width/height

Comment: use media query CSS

Comment: i alrady use media query..but this vartical bar only come in 67% zoom

Answer (score 1):

Unless you mean to apply the same rule to other places, set it manually to this table either with an inline `style` attribute or a `<style>` tag at the beginning of the page setting the table `overflow: hidden !important;`

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="table.dtOpt_SalesEntry" dt-column-defs="table.dtColDefs_SalesEntry" style="overflow: hidden !important;" class="row-border hover table-responsive display nowrap">
```

Comment: i try this but nothing will change...same issue

Comment: and one note this vartical scroll are come only in 67% zoom if i reduce to like 50% then it gone or if i zoom like more then 67% then also it will gone

Comment: Try putting the `overflow: hidden;` in the table parent tag and do the zooming again. If the scrollbar still show, keep moving it to the next parent tag until it doesn't and let me know the result.

Comment: Nothing happan..so i think it is template issue because i see in the template same problem available